# Extendable Multicore simulators

Tags: c, x86-64, multicore

Are there good simulators for x86-64 multicore processors. Also are they extendable, as if I want to simulate something by including my own hardware extension to the processor, can I add that extension to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use qemu-system-x64-86, use -M option to simulate particular cpu like core2duo also add -smp option to simulate number of core. In addition you can modify the qemu source code (it's opensource) to add new feature to simulate your particular hardware extension.